# UITableViewCell accessoryView not showing in iOS9

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

Trying to display a number on the right side of a table view cell in a label as an 'accessoryView', but the cell only displays the text of cell label.  What am I doing wrong?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style:.Default,reuseIdentifier:nil)        
    if let label = cell.textLabel {
        label.text = item.name
    }
    cell.selectionStyle     = .None

    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor         = UIColor.blackColor()
    label.text              = String(item.count)
    label.textAlignment     = .Right
    cell.accessoryView      = label

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think frame for UILabel is missing.

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45))
label.textColor         = UIColor.blackColor()
label.text              = String("8")
label.textAlignment     = .Right
cell.accessoryView      = label
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let label = UILabel()
label.textColor         = UIColor.blackColor()
label.text              = String(item.count)
label.textAlignment     = .Right
label.sizeToFit()     // ADD THIS LINE

cell.accessoryView      = label
```

Comment: As you commented, the note is to call the sizeToFit() method. Thanks @healthycola

Answer (score 1):

should check if you have this part of code on your tableView

```
tableView.editing = true
```

Or

```
tableView.setEditing(true, animated:animated)
```

accessoryView will be hidden if editing mode is true